# Manga about a boy who, after nearly dying, is brought back with superpowers

Tags: story-identification, manga, powers

So I'm trying to find a manga about a boy who gets killed but is experimented on, giving him his life back as well as superpowers.

In the first chapter we see him throw a stop sign at a speeding truck forcing it to stop.

I can't remember much else about it, so I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.